# PostgreSQL trigger not firing on update

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.4

There are two linked tables updated remotely: `table1` and `table2`

table2 uses foreign key dependance from table1.

Tables are updated in the following manner on remote server:

1. Insert into table1 returning id;
2. Insert into table2 using previous id
3. Query is sent ( 1 transaction with 2 insert statements)

I need to duplicate new rows to remote db using dblink so I created two 'before update' triggers  for table1 and table2;

The problem is that only table2 trigger is firing; the first isn't ( from remote update;
doing test query from pgadmin under the same user, I get both triggers fired OK )

I assumed it is because the update is being processed in 1 transaction/query on remote server. So I tried to process both tables in second trigger, but still no luck - only table2 is processed.

What could be the reason ?

Thanks

P.S.

Trigger codes

**Version 1**

```
PROCEDURE fn_replicate_data:

DECLARE

BEGIN 

PERFORM DBLINK_EXEC('myconn','INSERT INTO table1(dataid,sessionid,uid)  VALUES('||new.dataid||','||new.sessionid||',
'||new.uid||') ');

RETURN new;
END;

PROCEDURE fn_replicate_data2:

DECLARE
BEGIN 
PERFORM DBLINK_EXEC('myconn','INSERT INTO table2(dataid,data)       VALUES('||new.dataid||','''||new.data||''') ');

RETURN new;
END;



CREATE TRIGGER tr_remote_insert_data
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_replicate_data();

CREATE TRIGGER tr_remote_insert_data2
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table2
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_replicate_data2();
```

**VERSION2**

```
PROCEDURE fn_replicate_data:

DECLARE
var table1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
        select * from table1 into var where dataid = new.dataid;  
        PERFORM DBLINK_EXEC('myconn','INSERT INTO table1(dataid,sessionid,uid) VALUES('||var.dataid||','||var.sessionid||','||var.uid||')  ');


    PERFORM 
    DBLINK_EXEC('myconn','INSERT INTO table2(dataid,data)   VALUES('||new.dataid||','''||new.data||''') ');

    RETURN new;
    END;


    CREATE TRIGGER tr_remote_insert_data
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table2
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_replicate_data();
```

Comment: added triggers code above; in both cases only table2 is replicated, table1 isn't

Comment: Have you tried looking at FDW? This is the follow-up to dbconn and much easier to work with. Once set up, you effectively work with `table1` and `table2` as if they are local relations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in NULL value if uid field. It had bigint type and had no default value in db, which causes the trigger to not work properly.

The fix is either

```
IF (NEW.uid IS NULL )
     THEN  
     uid := 'DEFAULT';
     else
     uid :=  NEW.uid;
     END IF;
```

before insert query; or (simpler) adding default value to db;